# Who is supposed to pass 'handleSubmit'

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm looking at [WidgetForm.js](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/blob/master/src/components/WidgetForm/WidgetForm.js) sample in [react-redux-universal-hot-example](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example) (the most popular react+redux boilerplate). At the end there's a button that calls handleSubmit to send data to the server:

```
<button className="btn btn-success"
              onClick={handleSubmit(() => save(values)...
```

I'm confused where handleSubmit function comes from. I checked [Widgets](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/blob/master/src/containers/Widgets/Widgets.js) container and it doesn't pass it when renders WidgetForm. Is it injected automatically by a plugin? Or is done at a higher level? I'm quite new to react+redux and I'm lost.

Comment: Did you try running this code. If yes, did you get any warning saying something like - prop handleSubmit is required but not provided.

Comment: Looking at the code it looks like the function is supposed to be passed as a prop but its parent is not passing it as a prop

Comment: I'm playing with this code right now, it works perfectly. Here's the page: https://react-redux.herokuapp.com/widgets You press edit and then save - no errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `handleSubmit` prop is the submit handler passed down from [redux form](http://redux-form.com/6.4.1/docs/api/Props.md/#-handlesubmit-eventorsubmit-function-) via the decorator:

```
@reduxForm({
  form: 'widget',
  fields: ['id', 'color', 'sprocketCount', 'owner'],
  validate: widgetValidation
})
export default class WidgetForm extends Component {
```

In context you pass this component an `onSubmit` function that is called later by the `handleSubmit` callback. This allows redux form to perform validation, gather the form values, return errors etc. when the form is submitted via any action.

Answer (score 0):

It is confusing but if you look at line 34 you will see

```
const { editStop, fields: {id, color, sprocketCount, owner}, formKey, handleSubmit, invalid,
  pristine, save, submitting, saveError: { [formKey]: saveError }, values } = this.props;
```

If you were to remove this handleSubmit from this aliasing your button would look like

```
<button className="btn btn-success"
              onClick={this.props.handleSubmit(() => save(values)...
```